# Select multiple column in groupBy laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-5.7

I am using **Laravel 5.7** and i need to generate top selling products of current month for my reports. So i join two table `products` and `sells`. I want three columns in return which are **sell_quantity**, **product_name***, and ***product_id***.

So i pass those three column inside **selectRaw** and the query is like below:

```
 $top_items = Sell::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'sells.product_id')->selectRaw('sum(sells.quantity) as quantity, products.name, product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->limit(10)->orderBy('sells.quantity', 'desc')->get();
```

But when i execute i got an error which said **products.name** isn't in GROUP BY. My question is it required to pass all the parameter in select which i placed inside groupBy.

Comment: It is required to pass all non-aggregated parameters so you need to provide `product_id` and `products.name` but you are not required to pass the `sum`. That's because it is possible to have multiple different `products.name` corresponding to the same `product_id` (MySQL does not know that this is not the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$top_items = Sell::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
    ->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'sells.product_id')
    ->selectRaw('sum(sells.quantity) as quantity, products.name, sells.product_id')
    ->groupBy('sells.product_id', 'products.name')
    ->limit(10)
    ->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.

Is it mandatory to put the fields inside ```groupBy``` should be the same inside ```SelectRaw```.

The previous issue is working on ```Laravel 8```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly, then instead of groupBy you can use unique:

$top_items = Sell::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'sells.product_id')->selectRaw('sum(sells.quantity) as quantity, products.name, product_id')->limit(10)->orderBy('sells.quantity', 'desc')->get()->unique('product_id');

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 ways

1. When using group by, you should include all the selecting fields in the `GroupBy` function

> $top_items = Sell::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'sells.product_id')->selectRaw('sum(sells.quantity) as quantity, products.name, product_id')->groupByRaw('sum(sells.quantity), products.name, product_id')->limit(10)->orderBy('sells.quantity', 'desc')->get();

2. Disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, You can disable in Environment variables / extensions

> Not recommended